Expression not clear/ too long
Wolfram Alpha does not compute anything when I ask it to simplify this:
Divide[\(40)a*b\(41),2]Power[\(40)1-Divide[y,b]\(41),2]-Divide[\(40)a*b\(41),2]*Divide[Power[\(40)a-x-Sqrt[Divide[\(40)Power[\(40)a-c\(41),2]+Power[b,2]\(41),Power[b,2]]-1]*y\(41),2],Power[a,2]]-a*b*Divide[Power[\(40)Sqrt[Power[\(40)a-c\(41),2]+Power[b,2]]-Divide[Sqrt[Power[\(40)a-c\(41),2]+Power[b,2]]*y,b]-Divide[Sqrt[Power[\(40)a-c\(41),2]+Power[b,2]]*\(40)a-x-Sqrt[Divide[\(40)Power[\(40)a-c\(41),2]+Power[b,2]\(41),Power[b,2]]-1]*y\(41),a]\(41),2],2*Power[\(40)Sqrt[Power[\(40)a-c\(41),2]+Power[b,2]]\(41),2]]

Could anyone please help?

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! This site is strictly about programming in Wolfram Language, and questions about Wolfram|Alpha are considered off-topic here. Also, why are you using all this Divide and Power? You can simply use the regular notation: 40*a/b - 21 ....

This expression looks like it was written by a machine. Maybe ask the person who wrote the code that wrote this expression?

The site community.wolfram.com is open to questions about W|A.

WolframAlpha has a relatively small fixed buffer size.. It used to be smaller, but a while back I think it was increased to something like 125 characters. Input longer than that gives unpredictable results, sometimes nothing at all

Define the expression as a string:
S = "Divide[\(40)a*b\(41),2]Power[\(40)1-Divide[y,b]\(41),2]-Divide[\(40)\
a*b\(41),2]*Divide[Power[\(40)a-x-Sqrt[Divide[\(40)Power[\(40)a-c\(41)\
,2]+Power[b,2]\(41),Power[b,2]]-1]*y\(41),2],Power[a,2]]-a*b*Divide[\
Power[\(40)Sqrt[Power[\(40)a-c\(41),2]+Power[b,2]]-Divide[Sqrt[Power[\
\(40)a-c\(41),2]+Power[b,2]]*y,b]-Divide[Sqrt[Power[\(40)a-c\(41),2]+\
Power[b,2]]*\(40)a-x-Sqrt[Divide[\(40)Power[\(40)a-c\(41),2]+Power[b,\
2]\(41),Power[b,2]]-1]*y\(41),a]\(41),2],2*Power[\(40)Sqrt[Power[\(40)\
a-c\(41),2]+Power[b,2]]\(41),2]]";

Do some string editing to get rid of the \( sequences, then convert to a Mathematica expression and simplify:
StringReplace[S, {"\(" -> "("}] // ToExpression // FullSimplify


